# BASH: Get value directly after option

Tags: bash, parameters, arguments, args

I'm writing a bash script and need to get some parameters arg1, arg2,... and I need to get multiple ones at once and sometimes, but not always.
The problem is now, that with the code I can only grab the value if it is at position 2 of the whole command. (So with 2 arguments I already have a probem) How can I grab the input directly after the --argumentone parameter?  No matter if it's the first or the last argument.

```
for arg in "$@" ; do
        case "$arg" in
        --argumentone)
            VARLUE1=$2
            ;;
        --argumenttwo)
            VALUE2=$2
            ;;
esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't from a `for` loop. You need to use a `while` loop:

```
while (( $# )); do
    curr=$1
    shift
    case $curr in
        --argumentone) VALUE1=$2; shift ;;
        --argumenttwo) VALUE2=$2; shift ;;
    esac
done
```

If you don't want to modify `$@` while processing the list, you can use a index, incrementing it when you would use `shift` above:

```
i=1
while ((i <= $#)); do
    curr=${!i}
    ((i += 1))
    case $curr in
        --argumentone) VALUE1=${!i}; ((i+=1));;
        --argumenttwo) VALUE2=${!i}; ((i+=1));;
    esac
done
```